# Joint PDF of a Uniform Distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution

***The Question***
I have a sample X1,...,Xn i.i.d. 
drawn from a uniform distribution $unif[0,\theta]$, θ ∈ Θ = R+;

And I'd just like to compute the joint PDF

---

***The Solution***
I have the following solution supplied to me:
$$
f(\mathbf{X}:\theta) = \left( \frac{1}{\theta} \right)^{n} 1_{\{ X_{(n)} \leq \theta  \}}
$$

Where $X_{(n)} = max_{i=1,2,\ldots,n} \{ X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n} \}$

---

***Where I'm Stuck***
My PDF for this distribution will be:
$$
f(X) = 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{\theta}&, X_{i} \leq \theta \\ 
 0&, X_{i} > \theta
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

As the observations are independent, my joint distribution is simply:
$$
\begin{align*} 
l(X:\theta) &= \prod^{n}_{i=1} f(X_{i})\\
&= \prod^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{\theta} \cdot 1_{\{X_{i} \leq \theta\}} \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{\theta} \right) ^{n}   \prod^{n}_{i=1} 1_{\{X_{i} \leq \theta\}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Is the supplied solution just saying that we need *all* observations to be less than $\theta$ for the joint PDF to yeild something non-trivial?

Comment: The supplied solution is incorrect.  The indicator also needs to specify that all $X_i$ are non-negative.  Equivalently, it would suffice to stipulate $X_{(1)}\ge 0$.  Your answer $\prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$ is correct but then the same mistake creeps into your use of the indicator function.  (Note that $f(X) = (1/\theta)I(0\lt X \le \theta)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A product of indicator functions equals 1 if and only if every indicator in the product equals 1. In this case your product of indicators equals 1 iff all $X_i \leq \theta$ which is equivalent to the maximum, $X_{(n)}$, being less than or equal to $\theta$.

What you have is identical to the answer, just in a less compact form. Beyond simple convenience, we also like to write it in the way that the solution gives because that points to the fact that $X_{(n)}$ is sufficient for $\theta$.